# Query returning null values but there is no error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am picking values from a column `TRANSAMT` from the table `GLPJD`. The value can be negative in the table but when it's negative, I have to make it positive and when its positive, I leave it like that. The result being returned in NULL, what is left in the query. It is a subquery

```
declare @FY int
set @FY = 2016

SELECT
    DbName, District,
    (SELECT 
         CASE   
            WHEN (TRANSAMT < 0) 
               THEN ISNULL(SUM(TRANSAMT) * -1, 0) 
               ELSE ISNULL(SUM(TRANSAMT), 0)  
         END  
     FROM 
         GLPJD 
     LEFT JOIN 
         GLAMF ON GLPJD.ACCTID = GLAMF.ACCTID  
     WHERE 
         GLPJD.AUDTORG = D.DbName 
         AND GLPJD.ACCTID = 110002 
         AND GLPJD.FISCALYR < @FY 
     GROUP BY
         TRANSAMT) AS TRANSAMT
FROM
    Districts D
```

Results of the query:

[image: results of the query]

Comment: Mostly likely your subquery is logically invalid - but you don't have sufficient test data to understand that. Grouping by TRANSAMT will result in a row for every unique value of TRANSAMT. As soon as your test data finds multiple values for a given district, your query will fail with an error. I will hazard a guess that you want just one summed value per district. If so, start over. Regardless, since this is a subquery you don't need a left join - your null handling must occur "outside" the subquery because it might not find any rows in GLPJD.

Comment: Can you kindly let send me a correction of the query.i need help now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes probably from the fact that performing a SUM while having NULL values returns a NULL result. So you should use the ISNULL part inside SUM, and not the other way around.

Also you may consider using the function ABS, so you could get rid of the CASE part. My approach would be changing this part from your current code:

```
SELECT 
         CASE   
            WHEN (TRANSAMT < 0) 
               THEN ISNULL(SUM(TRANSAMT) * -1, 0) 
               ELSE ISNULL(SUM(TRANSAMT), 0)  
         END
```

To just:

```
SELECT SUM(ABS(ISNULL(TRANSAMT, 0)))
```

Comment: I still get NULL as the results,what is wrong with the query,what is really wrong

Comment: @lytakyn Are you sure that the WHERE condition applied to GLPJD is returning any rows? If that SELECT column returns 0 rows, you would get also a NULL as column value.

Answer (score 0):

sum function omits null values
look:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a806/1